# Failed to load resource net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. ERROR in my Server or Code

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iis

I have application on ASP.NET CORE 5.0. The application is served over [admin.vizz.az](http://admin.vizz.az/). I get the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. This is not a browser issue. An error associated with a code or server. 2 Javascript files cannot be read by html.

Debug time works great. The problem occurs when I publish via IIS

### **My HTML head**

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
            <style>
                #map {
                    height: 100%;`enter code here`
                    /* The height is 400 pixels */
                    width: 100%;
                    /* The width is the width of the web page */
                }
            </style>
            <script src="~/js/API.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/ChangeLoc.js"></script>
        </head>
    </html>
```

### **MY javascript addresses**

[APİ.js](http://admin.vizz.az/js/API.js)

[ChangeLoc.js](http://admin.vizz.az/js/ChangeLoc.js)

### **My Error**

[image]

### **PROBLEM**

I don't know how to solve it. Your help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: How you access this site, http or https? It seems that `Content-Security-Policy` will force those js file to https. Please disable this header and access again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used additional tag in HTML plugin. This forces the protocol of all forwarded links to https.

Uninstalling it worked for me

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```